# Creating stackables in my inventory system

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

While attempting to build an inventory system including stackables. The inventory system works great, except for the *stackables* part.

Right now, I've hit a full stop due to an infinite loop.

Here's the code, with comments, so hopefully you'll be able to understand what I was trying to accomplish.

```
    void AddItem(int id, int count) 
    {
    while(count > 0) // Continue running as long as there is an item to be added
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < inventory.Count; i++) // Search through the inventory
        {
            if(inventory[i].itemID == id) // We've found an item with the appropriate ID
            {
                int maxAdd = inventory[i].itemMaxStack - inventory[i].itemCurrStack; // Figure out how much we can add to this stack

                if(count > maxAdd) // There's not enough room to fit the entire stack, so add what we can and continue the -for- loop
                {
                    inventory[i].itemCurrStack = inventory[i].itemMaxStack;
                    count -= maxAdd;
                    continue;
                }

                if(count <= maxAdd) // There's enough room to fit the entire stack, so add it in.
                {
                    inventory[i].itemCurrStack += count;
                    count = 0;
                }

                if(inventory[i].itemCurrStack == inventory[i].itemMaxStack) // We found a stack, but it's already full, so continue the -for- loop
                {
                    continue;
                }
            } else if(inventory[i].itemName == null) // There were no items with the specified ID, so let's create one.
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < database.items.Count; j++)
                {
                    if(database.items[j].itemID == id)
                    {
                        inventory[i] = database.items[j];
                        break; // Break out of the -for- loop, since we've found what we're looking for.
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you used your debugger and stepped through the code? There's one of several possibilities. Either `count` is never `<= 0` so your `while` loop runs forever, you never reach your `break` statement, or one of your `for` loops is iterating way more times than you expect. You should use your debugger to narrow down the problem area, we can't exactly run this code but you can. BTW, nice commenting on the code!

Comment: Welcome. Please always include the applicable target platform you write for as a Tag: WPF, winforms ASP... unless it only aboutC# and/or  .NET in general!

Comment: @tnw Thanks. I couldn't troubleshoot in Unity, considering it freezes instantly when hitting an infinite loop. I've done a bit with Monodevelop, though, and it seems to hit the snag while checking my item database looking for a specific item ID. I'll have another look at it a bit later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't really need to do this with a loop. You can just stack the difference between the source and the target's max, and if there's any left, just dump it in the inventory as a new stack.

Edit: Added a little more plumbing to clarify, based on your comment. This is significantly different than your original question, but it demonstrates my point.

```
public abstract class Loot
{
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public virtual int MaxCount { get; set; }
}

public class Inventory : ICollection<Loot>
{
    public void Stack(Loot source, Loot target)
    {
        var availableOnTarget = target.MaxCount - target.Count;
        var amountToStack = Math.Min(availableOnTarget, source.Count);
        target.Count += amountToStack;
        source.Count -= amountToStack;
        if (target.Count == target.MaxCount && source.Count > 0)
        {
            this.Add(source);
        }
    }

    // ICollection implementation...
}

// This could be in Inventory, or the Player, or a gameplay manager...
// Personally I'd implement it in the Inventory class, if there was only
// one player with only one inventory. I'm sticking to the semantics of
// my first version, though.
public class Caller
{
    public void TryAddItemToInventory<TLoot>(Inventory inventory, TLoot itemToAdd) where TLoot:Loot
    {
        var sourceType = itemToAdd.GetType();
        var stackTarget = inventory.OfType<TLoot>().First(i => i.Count < i.MaxCount);
        if (stackTarget != null)
        {
            inventory.Stack(itemToAdd, stackTarget);
        }
        else
        {
            inventory.Add(itemToAdd);
        }

        // You need to check if the inventory exists, if it has enough room to accommodate
        // the item, what happens to overflow, etc. Left all that out for brevity.
    }
}
```

Comment: Talk about refactoring.

Comment: It's just a simplified example; I don't know enough about the business objects and rules to write copypasta for him.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Sadly, I'm not sure that this would work. Right now, I'm trying to search through a list of inventory slots, an 8x4 grid, and find the first stack of an item that has room, or create a new stack in an empty slot. It seems like what you suggested would already need to know _where_ the item would be going, and that's one of the things I was trying to accomplish in my code.

Comment: You can FIND the item (target) in a loop, then call your Stack method if a viable stack exists, otherwise call the Add method.